# Examples of in-band signalling hacks?

Tags: sql-injection, injection

In-band signalling or the mixing of control and metadata on the same channel is what allowed the early phone phreakers to obtain free calls on telecommunications systems. By sending control tones through telephone receivers where only user data was expected they were able to connect free of charge etc. I was wondering if people knew of other examples of hacks or errors that have been a result of mixing control data and metadata in the same channel?, if anyone knew of examples affecting other systems say traffic cameras or radio controls?.

This example has circulated on the internet for some years and is theoretical/ humorous but I was wondering has there been any successful injection attacks using camera input ? [image]

Comment: Welcome on Security SE. As said in my answer, please select a specific threat and try to dedicate your question and title to it. As it is now it is very broad and not adapted to this site Q&A format. I took the camera injection mainly because of your picture which seems to highlight this threat, but you question covers a too wide area. You can freely edit your own posts by using the [edit] link below your post. In case of doubt, do not hesitate to add a comment, precede usernames with a '@' so they receive a notification of your messages.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitively restrict the range of your question and update the title accordingly. I'm answering here to your last question "*has there been any successful injection attacks using camera input ?*".

Yes, I think you can say so. I'm particularly referring to [a vulnerability which affected Google glasses](http://www.slashgear.com/google-glass-exploit-hacked-wearable-with-qr-codes-17290717/).

The Google glass would detect and handle automatically some type of QR codes, so some people had the idea to print specially crafted QR codes (exactly same principle as your SQL injection car plate, but here with a QR code instead of a literal string) which will automatically trigger this functionality in the Google glass and allow the attacker to take control of the Google glass internal system (accessing data, etc.).

No user notification nor interaction, all that is needed is for the malicious QR Code to be seen by the Google glass camera.